# Adding Mac App Distribution Certificates

Tags: macos, code-signing, mac-app-store, xcode5.0.1

I'm trying to add Distribution Certificates for my Mac App (for distribution outside the Mac App Store).

However I stumbled upon this:

[image: Problem]

I am unable to select the **Developer ID** option. It is disabled. I have revoked all my Certificates in the Production Panel as well as in the Development Panel but still with no luck.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It might be because you need to set in Xcode that you intend to distribute your application outside of the Mac App Store and then request Developer ID certificates.

Go to the Xcode project settings and under Signing, select Developer ID as the signing identity. After that Xcode will help you to create a Developer ID Certificate for you.

Refer the doc for more details :

[App Distribution Guide - Apple](http://bit.ly/16nTzuJ)

Comment: I actually was able to create Developer ID certificates before. Then I was having some issues with the private keys. Then I decided to follow Apple's advice which is to revoke and start fresh. So, I revoked everything. However, after revoking, I wasn't able to delete or add new certificates anymore. I have also read from other developers that they're having the same issues as I have. I've already sent a report to Apple, I just don't know when they'll be able to fix this.